# What's the difference between "gelingen" and "gelangen"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What are the differences between *gelingen* and *gelangen*? I am confused about the usage differences between *to succeed* and *to reach*.

Comment: Does it help to have two examples?_Der Plan gelingt (the plan succeeds)_  and _Ich gelangte an das Ziel (I reached the goal)_

Comment: They are completely different words, with unrelated meanings. Any dictionary will tell you what each of them means.

Comment: Apart from sharing the same past tense forms, they don't have anything in common. They are unrelated, as chirlu pointed out.

Comment: @chirlu, aparently OP *did* check a dictionary...

Comment: @Chieron same past tense? I don't agree at all.

Comment: @Stephie: I don’t see evidence of using a dictionary; in any case, there is no explanation of why it didn’t help. And I assume Chieron meant that there is some overlap between present forms of _gelangen_ and preterite forms of _gelingen_. (_Auf welchem Weg gelangen wir zu dem Aussichtspunkt, von dem aus uns letztes Jahr so schöne Fotos gelangen?_)

Comment: I don't see any German specific question. If one *succeed*s, one has obviously *reached* the goal. Only the past gets mildly interesting due to irregular verb. *Bist du am Gipfel angelangt, ist dir die Bergbesteigung gelungen*.

Comment: So, what's the difference between *to succeed* and *to reach*. Once you've answered that question, you know the difference between the German words.

Answer (score 3):

**Gelingen** focuses on the successful outcome:
a plan that works out, a cake that turns out or a sports move that went as planned can all "gelingen".

**Gelangen** refers to reaching some position, either in a purely spatial or figurative sense; it can indicate some effort or coincidence:
A traveler arriving at a town, a manager reaching a certain position, a message in a bottle washing up on a shore or chemicals being found in the food chain may all "gelangen".